# In Flash Builder, how do I make a <s:List> dataprovider="certain part of an Array"?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a List, and I have an ArrayCollection.

The ArrayCollection is something like:
   `<mx:ArrayCollection id="arrColl">`
      `<mx:source>`
         `<mx:Array>`
            `<mx:Object label="Student A" score="85,36,43,67,54,47" />`
           `<mx:Object label="Student B" score="85,36,43,67,54,47" />`
          `<mx:Object label="Student C" score="85,36,43,67,54,47" />`
        `</mx:Array>`
     `</mx:source>`
`</mx:ArrayCollection>`

I need the List to only display the scores of the student.

Something like:

`<s:List dataprovider="arrColl[Student A]"/>`
or:
`<s:List dataprovider="arrColl.Student A."/>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the list control wont pick up this "34,65,36,87,12" variable and turn it into a IList List.

I figured it out, I first have to do this: studentAArray = new ArrayCollection(arrColl.score.split(",")); Then use studentAArray as the List dataprovider.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything with the list to make this happen.  You want to apply a filter to the ArrayCollection.  The list will immediately pick up the filter, and remove invalid items from the view.

Set the dataProvider like this:

```
<s:List dataprovider="arrColl"/>
```

Then create a [filterFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction), something like this:

```
public function StudentAFilter(item:Object):void{
  if(item['label'] = "Student A"){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And somewhere in your code, do something like this:

```
arrColl.filterFunction = StudentAFilter;
arrColl.refresh()
```

The code above is often related to a button click or the change handler of a drop down list; depending how you want the user to filter the data.

Comment: The problem is that the list control wont pick up this "34,65,36,87,12" variable and turn it into a IList List.

Comment: I figured it out, I first have to do this: studentAArray = new ArrayCollection(arrColl.score.split(","));  Then use studentAArray as the List dataprovider.

Comment: @Nathan Johnson I didn't realize that you wanted to get the "Score" variable and use it as the dataProvider. If possible avoid using comma separated lists.  I have to wonder what is populating your data in such a way.

Comment: How would I store that value in a database if not for a comma separated list?

Comment: @Nathan Johnson In a separate table linked to the main table w/ a foreign keys.  You would have a student table (StudentID, StudentName), and a Score table (ScoreID, Score, StudentID). You may benefit from reading up on relational database theory, specifically the normal forms.  Storing data in the database as comma separated lists always makes me cringe.